# Tweepy API: unable to get queries to return user_fields

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I've got a python flask app whose job is to work with the Twitter V2.0 API. I got to using the Tweepy API in my app because I was having difficulty cold coding the [3 legged auth flow](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens). Anyway, since I got that working, I'm now running into difficulties executing some basic queries, like [get_me()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_me) and [get_user()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_user)

This is my code:

```
    client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=private.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret=private.API_KEY_SECRET,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

    user = client.get_me(expansions='author_id', user_fields=['username','created_at','location'])
    print(user)
    return('success')
```

And this is invariably the error:
tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
The `expansions` query parameter value [author_id] is not one of [pinned_tweet_id]

Per the [Twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-me) for this endpoint, this should certainly work...I fail to understand why I the 'pinned_tweet_id' expansion is the particular issue.

I'm left wondering if I'm missing something basic here or if Tweepy is just a POS and I should considering rolling my own queries like I originally intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to drop the 'expansions' kwag and leave 'user_fields' as is. I was further confused by the fact that printing the returned user object *does not* show the requested user_fields as part of the data attribute. You have to explicitly access them through the data attribute, as below.

[image: code]

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

### Tweet Author ID

You may have read the Twitter Docs incorrectly as the expansions parameter value has only `pinned_tweet_id`, and the tweet fields parameter has the `author_id` value you're looking for. Here is a screenshot for better clarification:

[image: Twitter Docs]

The code would look like:

```
    client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=private.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret=private.API_KEY_SECRET,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

    user = client.get_me(tweet_fields=['author_id'], user_fields=[
                     'username', 'created_at', 'location'])
    print(user)
    return('success')
```

### User ID

If you're looking for the **user id** then try omitting tweet_fields and add `id` in the `user_fields` also shown in the Twitter Docs.
[image: Twitter Docs 2]

The code would look like:

```
    client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=private.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret=private.API_KEY_SECRET,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

    user = client.get_me(user_fields=['id', 'username', 'created_at', 'location'])
    print(user)
    return('success')
```

You can obtain the user id with `user.data.id`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. the returned user.data object fails to include any of the desired attributes (username, created_at, location).

Comment: Also, the methods I have mentioned are designed to return user objects, not tweet objects. tweet.fields/tweet_fields shouldn't come into play here.

Comment: In that case you can omit tweet_fields and add 'id' to user_fields, then print out user.data.id. Unfortunately user.data doesn't show all the attributes by default.